# Where is the Spatial reference ID stored in SpatiaLite?

Tags: coordinate-system, spatialite

I have loaded a shapefile into a SpatiaLite Database using the spatialite-gui. In which table is the Spatial reference ID or EPSG code (of the stored data)stored in SpatiaLite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table that holds the description is spatial_ref_sys. The id is contained in the [geometry binary blob](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html).

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong here, but when I run "select aswkt(geometry) from Buildings where Id =3;" I do not get the epsg code in the output. Does that mean that the spatial reference for my Buildings Table is not saved?

Comment: No, it means that the WKT format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) doesn't specify the SRID. Try AsEwkt() if you'd like the SRID included. You can also just ask for SRID(geometry) if you just want the id. Note that there is a chance that your SRID is not an EPSG SRID, but its unlikely unless you used something exotic on input.

Comment: Basically I wanted to project Geometries to a UTM projection if they were not in UTM already, so as to get distances in Meters. I see that SRID(Geometry) also works when you use it in a query. Thanks.

Comment: That should be no problem (as long as you know which UTM zone you want). http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.0.0.html#p15 will give you the Transform() function.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: does this answer the question / solve your problem for now?

Comment: It does solve my issue. I had assumed that like PostGIS, there would be a table similar to 'geometry_columns' which would give the srid for each of my tables. Hence I was searching for it. I can make do with querying the srid from the individual table itself.

Comment: There is a geometry_columns table as well - see http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html. You can find all the tables in an sqlite database using the command line ".tables" (or other techniques at http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7).